# How do I store the results of a function into a list of some sort over time in Python?

Tags: python, list, function

So I'm refreshing what little I knew of Python before and playing around with some beginner projects. I'm toying arond with it now, and I'm just trying to learn and see what I can do. I made a "Guessing Game" and turned it into a function. I want to store these reults in a list each time it is used. I want the results to automatically go to the list when the game is completed and then to be able to print the list when desired.

I'm not sure if I need to create a new function for this, or if I should be creating this within my current "guessing_game" function. I've tried to create a list previously, but I'm not sure how to create and store the variable of the game result in order to add it into the list. I feel like this is probably a fairly simple problem, so I apologize if this is a dumb question.

```
def guessing_game():
    import random

    number = random.randint(1, 1000)
    player_name = input("Enter name ")
    number_of_guesses = 0


    print('Howdy' + player_name + "Guess a number between 1 and 1000: ")

    while number_of_guesses < 10:
        guess = int(input())
        number_of_guesses += 1
        if guess < number:
            print("Too Low, Joe")
        if guess > number:
            print("Too high, Sly")
        if guess == number:
            break

    if guess == number:
        print("You got it, Bobbit, in " + str(number_of_guesses) + " tries")
    else:
        print(" Well, yer were close, Stofe. Shoulda guessed " + str(number))

print(guessing_game())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list inside of the function, and then everytime they guess, you can store the guess inside the list. At the end, we can print the list.

```python
def guessing_game():
    import random

    number = random.randint(1, 1000)
    player_name = input("Enter name: ")
    number_of_guesses = 0
    guesses = []


    print('Howdy ' + player_name + " Guess a number between 1 and 1000: ")

    while number_of_guesses < 10:
        guess = int(input())
        guesses.append(guess)
        number_of_guesses += 1
        if guess < number:
            print("Too Low, Joe")
        if guess > number:
            print("Too high, Sly")
        if guess == number:
            break

    if guess == number:
        print("You got it, Bobbit, in " + str(number_of_guesses) + " tries")
    else:
        print(" Well, yer were close, Stofe. Shoulda guessed " + str(number))
    
    print("These were the numbers you guessed:")
    for g in guesses:
        print(g)

print(guessing_game())
```

Comment: Thanks. This gives me a better idea, but I was looking more to record the final results of the game (number of guesses and the actual number) rather than all of the individual guesses. Any chance you would have some advice on this?

Comment: In this case, instead of guesses being a list, we can set it to 0. Instead of `guesses.append(guess)`, we can increment it by saying `guesses += 1`. At the end, `guesses` will have the total number of guesses.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create a list with something like `val = []`. I added it into the code and also added a formatting piece so it looks nice.

```py
def guessing_game():
    import random
    guesses = []
    number = random.randint(1, 1000)
    guess = number / 2
    player_name = input("Enter name ")
    number_of_guesses = 0

    print(f'Howdy {player_name}. Guess a number between 1 and 1000: ')

    while number_of_guesses < 10:
        guess = int(input('> '))
        guesses = guesses + [guess]
        number_of_guesses += 1
        if guess < number:
            print("Too Low, Joe")
        if guess > number:
            print("Too high, Sly")
        if guess == number:
            break
    formatted_guesses = ''
    for _ in range(len(guesses)):
        if _ != len(guesses) - 1:
            formatted_guesses = formatted_guesses + str(guesses[_]) + ', '
        else:
            formatted_guesses = formatted_guesses + str(guesses[_]) + '.'
    if guess == number:
        print("You got it, Bobbit, in " + str(number_of_guesses) + " tries")
        print(f'You guessed {formatted_guesses}')
    else:
        print("Well, yer were close, Stofe. Shoulda guessed " + str(number))
        print(f'You guessed {formatted_guesses}')


guessing_game()
```